# Is there a way to set a this variable based on parameter being passed into a function

Tags: angular

I was wondering if it's possible to set a this variable in angular from a function. Example in code

```
function(...querystrings) {
    for (let index = 0; index < queryStrings.length; index++) {
      var key = Object.keys(queryStrings[index]).toString();
      if(Array.isArray(queryStrings[index][key])) {
        this.{{variable I want to change}} = something;
      }
    }
```

Basically what I'm trying to do is pass in multiple objects, go through each of the key value pairs, and based on what the value is (in the example here if the value is an array), I want to change the this variable associated with it.

I.E. If I had a this variable of this.variable = ["something", "something"], then I want to change this.variable's value to something else.

If it helps to visualize it, the code would be something like this.Object.keys(queryStrings[index]).toString() = something else

Comment: This[variable] ... but that is quite a code smell. You might want to rethink this..

Comment: How so? At the beginning of my career, so any advice is good advice. Also, this[variable] works, thanks

Answer (score 0):

`this` is immutable which means not possible to assign value to it. `this` represents execution context.

> In most cases, the value of this is determined by how a function is
>   called. It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be
>   different each time the function is called.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this